# svelte-sapper each block list item selection for deletion - get the id

Tags: sapper, svelte-3

I have a list of orders stored in a db. I use each block to display all orders with a delete button. When I click the delete button, I need to get the id of the CLICKED list item so I can look that order in the db and delete it. I don't know how to get the id of the CLICKED list item and pass it to handledelete function. How do I do that in svelte/sapper?

My code for the page that display all orders :

```
<script>
 
  let orderz =[]

  function handlesave() {
     //save all the order data to db...    
  } // handlesave


  function handleDelete () {
  

  fetch('order', {
  method: 'POST',
  credentials : 'include',
  headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-type' : 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
  // order id to send it to server to delete it from the db
   
  })
  }).then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJson => {
  console.log("xxxxxxx:", responseJson.orderdetails )      
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error));

}

</script>


<form on:submit|preventDefault={handlesave}>
  <button type="submit">Place Order</button>
</form>

<ul>
  {#each orderz as order}
  <li >
    <p >{order.vendorid} - {order.vendorname} - {order.item} 
         - {order.price}</p>
    <button on:click|once={handleDelete}>Delete</button>
  </li>
  
  {/each}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell the *delete* function which id was clicked by simply passing it in as an argument to the function:

```js
function handleDelete(id) {
  // Delete logic here
}
```

```html
<button on:click="{() => handleDelete(id)}">Delete</button>
```

!! Note that you should **not** call *handleDelete* directly in your markup as this will execute the function **immediately** upon rendering (and thus effectively delete your entry as soon as it appears on screen)

Answer (score 0):

Just add variable to your delete-function:

```
function handleDelete (id){
... use id to delete item in database...
}
```

Then add order id also to your on:click:

EDIT: on:click function call fixed as mentioned in other answer

```
 <button on:click|once={()=>handleDelete(order.id)}>Delete</button>
```

There are other ways to do this, but this is the simplest one.
You don’t need `once` modifier, if you delete the item.
You will probably need a key with `each`-loop in order to keep list correctly updated after delete (key = thing.id in following example)

```
{#each things as thing (thing.id)}
    <Thing current={thing.color}/>
{/each}
```

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks

Comment: The key suggestion was helpful. Thank you.